# Is there a way to automatically limit the amount of installed Linux kernels on a system?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, boot

The reason why I'm asking this is because a few days ago I ran out of disk space in `/boot` after a new kernel had been installed which let to a kernel panic (the initial ram disk couldn't be created out of lack of disk space).

I'm on Debian and I use `unattended-upgrades` which would automatically install a new kernel if there's been a security update.

Is there a way to automatically limit the amount of installed Linux kernels in order to prevent this from happening again in future?

Comment: Google. [How does 'apt' decide how many old kernels to keep?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620266/how-does-apt-decide-how-many-old-kernels-to-keep)

Comment: Also google. [How ‘apt’ Decides Number of Old Kernels to Keep: Explained](https://devicetests.com/apt-kernel-keep-explained).

Comment: How did you configure `unattended-upgrades`, have you uncommented the option `Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages "true";`?